# Pass file attachments from Ms Forms to Outlook using Logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that connects to Ms Forms and sends the result as an email.
The user can upload files to Ms Forms.  I don't know how many files the user will upload (could be zero) and I don't know the extension of any of these files.
How can I add these files as an attachment in the email sent by logic apps?
I'm using this connector to MsForms.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the workaround that you can try.

After using the trigger and the `Get response details` connector to add the attachments I used a `Compose` Connector in order to get the files that the person uploaded through MS Forms.

[image]

Compose Expression:
`json(body('Get_response_details_2')?['r13237ad0c60f42989d7ea61d8fee6482'])`

Then I'm using a `For_each` loop to retrieve the files from the previous step compose connector. In the following step I'm using One drive's `Get file content` Connector. As the each file will be saved with a unique Id I used to same to retrieve the file content and passed the same to `Send the email`.

[image]

Here is the code view of my Logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(body('Get_response_details_2')?['r13237ad0c60f42989d7ea61d8fee6482'])",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_response_details_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Get_file_content_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['onedriveforbusiness']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(item()?['id']))}/content"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Attachments": [
                                    {
                                        "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_file_content_2'))}",
                                        "Name": "@{item()?['id']}"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Body": "<p>My Files as Attachment</p>",
                                "Subject": "Sample Flow",
                                "To": "v-swethaka@microsoft.com"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/Mail"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_file_content_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@outputs('Compose')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_response_details_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['microsoftforms']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/formapi/api/forms('@{encodeURIComponent('v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR8k7o6rhlmJKk_S4R3vq7DZUQjM1VU5ONE1SRTNXVkI2N0pJTFVQM1gzMS4u')}')/responses",
                    "queries": {
                        "response_id": "@triggerBody()?['resourceData']?['responseId']"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_new_response_is_submitted": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "eventType": "responseAdded",
                        "notificationUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}",
                        "source": "ms-connector"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['microsoftforms']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/formapi/api/forms/@{encodeURIComponent('v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR8k7o6rhlmJKk_S4R3vq7DZUQjM1VU5ONE1SRTNXVkI2N0pJTFVQM1gzMS4u')}/webhooks"
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "microsoftforms": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your Subscription Id>/resourceGroups/<Your Resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/microsoftforms",
                    "connectionName": "microsoftforms",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/microsoftforms"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your Subscription Id>/resourceGroups/<Your Resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your Subscription Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/office365"
                },
                "onedriveforbusiness": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<Your Subscription Id>/resourceGroups/<Your Resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/onedriveforbusiness",
                    "connectionName": "onedriveforbusiness",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<Your Subscription Id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/onedriveforbusiness"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:- This causes the flow to have multiple emails (i.e., The number of files that the person has uploaded).

To have a single time to be triggered One workaround is to save all these links in one array variable and send the same to the email else you can also follow [How to send only one email with multiple attachments](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c1246d9-fe53-4a2e-b154-d875245c23a4/stuck-azure-logic-app-for-each-loop-sending-multiple-emaisl-each-time-how-to-send-only-one-email).